# How do I achieve the following layout - one fixed height views at the middle and two equal height views in the top and bottom?

Tags: android, layout

How do I achieve the following vertical layout in Android ?

```
View1
View2
View3
```

All three views have width that fits the screen.

`View2` height is fixed (= 100).
`View1` height is equal to `view3's` height.

Am I able to achieve this with `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`?

I'd appreciate if there is a programmatical solution, instead of the `XML` layout.

Comment: `Am I able to achieve this with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout?`. Yes, by using all those ones you can, And also by using TabLayout or GridLayout you can achieve the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using **`LinearLayout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want but you can [get screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels).

Subtract `View2's` height and just set heights of `View1` and `View3` to half of your result.

You need to use `RelativeLayout` and sort them as you want.